# finding a path using depth first search

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, path, depth-first-search

For school i need to make an assignment. We have to find a path between 2 vertices. I have given my code below, i almost got it working, but i am stuck at one part. In my find path function, in the second for loop, i want to check wether the node is in the stack, but because the node is a string and the "start" variable in the stack is an int, idk how to compare the values, so that we do not add another 1 to the stack, which is happening in my case.

this is the input:

```
1->5
1, 2; 2, 3; 3, 4; 4, 5; 5,
```

this is the correct output:

```
 1->2->3->4->5
```

however i get none as output. Below i have given my code. If anybody could help, it would be very much appreciated!

```
import sys
from typing import List

stack: []

def output():
    '''
    Will print the path stored in the `stack` global variable.
    You are free to modify it to be a parameter.
    '''
    for id in stack[:-1]:
        print(f'{id}->', end='')
    try:
        print(f'{stack[-1]}')
    except IndexError:
        pass


def find_path(graph, start, target, path):
    print(start, target)
    path = path + [start]
    print(path)
    if start == target:
        return path
    for node in graph:
        print(node)
        if node not in path: ##idk what to do here..
            new_path = find_path(graph, node, target, path)
            if new_path:
                return new_path


def add_value(dict_obj, key, value):
    if key not in dict_obj:
        dict_obj[key] = list()
    dict_obj[key].append(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    Fetch starting and target nodes.
    '''
    start, target = [int(x) for x in input().split('->')]
    #print(start, target)
    '''
    Fetch `;` separated twitter data. <id-1: u_int>, <following: u_int>, ..<following: u_int>; ... 
    i.e: 1, 2; 2, 3; 3, 4; 4, 5; 5,
    '''
    data = input()
    data_l: List = data.split(';')
    graph = dict()
    for d in data_l:
        id, followers = d.split(', ', 1)
        # print(followers)
        following_l: List = followers.split(', ')
        for f in following_l:
            if f == '':
                # node is not following other nodes.
                continue
        add_value(graph, id, followers)
    print(graph)
    find_path(graph, start, target, [])

sys.stdout.write(output())
```

Answer (score 3):

Modified the methods. Adding snippets of modified code here:

```
# Initialize stack properly   
stack = []
    
def output():
    # Print only if there are any nodes in stack
    return " -> ".join(stack) if stack else ""

def find_path(graph, start, target, path):
    ...
    # Missing return statement at end of the method call
    return path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Since you're comparing storing nodes as string in computation,
    # use the start and target as strings as well
    start, target = [x for x in input().split('->')]
    ...
    # Store returned output from your method in the stack variable
    stack = find_path(graph, start, target, [])
```

This works for the code you shared, however it can be written in a better and modular way. I'd recommend reading more about graph and its traversal examples.

Comment: Thanks, it works! though when i pass this input                        
1->4000000000                                                                            1, 2, 3; 2, 2; 3, 4, 5; 4, 1, 2; 5, 5, 4000000000; 4000000000, 2.   I still get 1-> 2-> 3-> 4-> 5-> 4000000000 even though the path could be shorter namely,1->3->5->4000000000. How can i optimize this?

Comment: I would say DFS and BFS are exhaustive approaches and aren't specialized in finding shortest path, I would suggest using Djistra for finding the shortest path. A* may be a more efficient approach which involves less computation (but doesn't ensure the shortest path as Djistra does in case the heuristics passed aren't close to being accurate)

Comment: Adding to @SyedMAbbasHaiderTaqvi comment, this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-unweighted-graph/) might be a good place for you to start looking at implementing a shortest path search.